# How do I print an exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

How do I print the error/exception in the `except:` block?

```
try:
    ...
except:
    print(exception)
```

Comment: Related: [How to print the full traceback without halting the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3702675/3357935)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch and print the full exception traceback without halting/exiting the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-catch-and-print-the-full-exception-traceback-without-halting-exiting-the)

Answer (score 1932, accepted):

For Python 2.6 and later and Python 3.x:

```
except Exception as e: print(e)
```

For Python 2.5 and earlier, use:

```
except Exception,e: print str(e)
```

Comment: `str( KeyError('bad'))` => `'bad'` -- doesn't tell exception type

Comment: print(e) on keyerrors seems to give only the key, but not the full exception message, which is less than helpful.

Comment: If you are going to print the exception, it is better to use `print(repr(e))`; the base `Exception.__str__` implementation only returns the exception message, not the type. Or, use the `traceback` module, which has methods for printing the current exception, formatted, or the full traceback.

Comment: You are right, but this prints only the exception text. This is often not useful to solve the problem that caused the exception. Thus I strongly prefer printing the traceback as in the solution below by @Cat Plus Plus!

E.g. I had an issue with an invalid unicode character during XML parsing and printing the exception showed only "invalid character" or so. Not very helpful. The full trace showed "UnicodeEncodeError: character '\u2212' --> with this information I was able to fix the issue by searching for '\u2212' in my XML file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the `print(repr(e))`  doesn't give any stracktrace. The `print_exc` from traceback module *(mentioned in the other answer)* though works in this case.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Where am I claiming that printing `repr(e)` would give the stack trace? I'm talking about the difference between `str(e)` and `repr(e)`, the latter includes more information that you would also see in the last line(s) of a traceback. I explicitly mention the `traceback` module in my comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters though you didn't, but you did recommend to use `print(repr(e))` specifically, whereas about the traceback you give some generic statement that it has various methods to print an exception. This sounds like you give preference to `repr()` way, and since your comment got so many upvotes, I thought it is worth writing a visible reply about what better method exists there.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I was focusing on printing _just_ the exception, and the traceback module has functions focusing on just the exception as well.

Answer (score 799):

The [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module provides methods for [formatting and printing exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples) and their tracebacks, e.g. this would print exception like the default handler does:

```
import traceback

try:
    1/0
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\scripts\divide_by_zero.py", line 4, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: is there some kind of get_error_message call that I can print with seeing as I'm using my own printing routine to add some other things.

Comment: @MikeSchem

```error_message = traceback.format_exc()```

Comment: This snipped does not use the captured exception object. Can you expand the code to use 'ex'? - as in `except Exception as ex:`...

Comment: @aaronsteers it does use the captured exception; in an exception handler the current exception is available via the `sys.exc_info()` function and the `traceback.print_exc()` function gets it from there. You’d only ever need to pass in an exception explicitly when not handling an exception or when you want to show info based on a different exception.

Comment: Yes, I would sometimes like to hold onto the exception and print it later, when I'm no longer in the 'except' block.

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much!
I was searching for ages for a way to get the whole exception text printed without actually throwing the exception. This is the solution :)

In my case the exception text said "invalid character" which did not help. THe trace said "UnicodeEncodeError: can't encode character '\u2212'." --> with this infomration I could find and fix the issue quickly. Thanks again! :)

Comment: How to get the string if I want to redirect to my own logger?

Comment: I think this should be the updated answer as the more upvoted is a but old and ignores the complete traceback that is important and provide useful information.

Answer (score 201):

In **Python 2.6 or greater** it's a bit cleaner:

```
except Exception as e: print(e)
```

In older versions it's still quite readable:

```
except Exception, e: print e
```

Comment: This solution was exactly said above! (see previous ones then write)

Answer (score 134):

## Python 3: `logging`

Instead of using the basic `print()` function, the more flexible [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module can be used to log the exception. The `logging` module offers a lot extra functionality, for example, logging messages...

- into a given log file, or
- with timestamps and additional information about where the logging happened.

For more information check out the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html).

---

### Usage

Logging an exception can be done with the module-level function [`logging.exception()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.exception) like so:

```py
import logging

try:
    1/0
except BaseException:
    logging.exception("An exception was thrown!")
```

#### Output

```
ERROR:root:An exception was thrown!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../Desktop/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

#### Notes

- the function `logging.exception()` should only be called from an exception handler
- the `logging` module should not be used inside a logging handler to avoid a `RecursionError` (thanks @PrakharPandey)

---

### Alternative log-levels

It's also possible to log the exception with another [log level](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels) but still show the exception details by using the keyword argument `exc_info=True`, like so:

```py
logging.critical("An exception was thrown!", exc_info=True)
logging.error   ("An exception was thrown!", exc_info=True)
logging.warning ("An exception was thrown!", exc_info=True)
logging.info    ("An exception was thrown!", exc_info=True)
logging.debug   ("An exception was thrown!", exc_info=True)

# or the general form
logging.log(level, "An exception was thrown!", exc_info=True)
```

---

### Name and description only

Of course, if you don't want the whole traceback but only some specific information (e.g., exception name and description), you can still use the `logging` module like so:

```py
try:
    1/0
except BaseException as exception:
    logging.warning(f"Exception Name: {type(exception).__name__}")
    logging.warning(f"Exception Desc: {exception}")
```

#### Output

```
WARNING:root:Exception Name: ZeroDivisionError
WARNING:root:Exception Desc: division by zero
```

Comment: Should not be used inside a logging handler to avoid RecursionError

Comment: In this example, the exception is logged and the exception is "handled". One may wish to re-raise this exception, if not sufficiently handled.

Comment: This "logging.exception()" is great! It has alwas worked well for me. When I, instead, logged "Exception" or anything in the other answers, sometimes it worked well, sometimes it printed another "error", sometimes it did not tell the filename and line number of the error, and sometimes it logged a wrong file and line number.

Comment: Excepting `BaseException` may be risky. See note for KeyboardInterrupt at the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt

Answer (score 78):

Expanding off of the "except Exception as e:" solution here is a nice one liner which includes some additional info like the type of error and where it occurred.

```py
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__} at line {e.__traceback__.tb_lineno} of {__file__}: {e}")
```

Output:

```
ZeroDivisionError at line 48 of /Users/.../script.py: division by zero
```

Comment: The most useful answer.

Comment: for me `pint(e)` only returns `Message:` nothing else in python 3.7 anaconda

Comment: had to scroll down too far to get the real answer.

Comment: It is maybe useful for the sake of example to know where to grab the information of the exception, but it is really clumsy if you think to handle all exceptions this way.

Comment: @JayZee, not clumsy if you write a function consisting of the print line in the answer and just pass the exception to that function from every exception block.

Comment: Great solution. I changed the `{__file__}` part to `{'/'.join(__file__.split('/')[3:])}` in order to only print the path that was relevant to me (it could be different for each case so just change the number which is 3 in my case).

Answer (score 76):

(I was going to leave this as a comment on @jldupont's answer, but I don't have enough reputation.)

I've seen answers like @jldupont's answer in other places as well. FWIW, I think it's important to note that this:

```py
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

will print the error output to `sys.stdout` by default. A more appropriate approach to error handling in general would be:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e, file=sys.stderr)
```

(Note that you have to `import sys` for this to work.) This way, the error is printed to `STDERR` instead of `STDOUT`, which allows for the proper output parsing/redirection/etc. I understand that the question was strictly about 'printing an error', but it seems important to point out the best practice here rather than leave out this detail that could lead to non-standard code for anyone who doesn't eventually learn better.

I haven't used the `traceback` module as in Cat Plus Plus's answer, and maybe that's the best way, but I thought I'd throw this out there.

Comment: I would suggest further adding flush=True. I've noticed with systemd (and not using a proper logging framework), that buffering when capturing to the journal is not what I would have expected.

Comment: @CameronKerr isn’t ‘stderr’ not buffered?

Answer (score 71):

In case you want to pass error strings, here is an example from [Errors and Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) (Python 2.6)

```
>>> try:
...    raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
... except Exception as inst:
...    print type(inst)     # the exception instance
...    print inst.args      # arguments stored in .args
...    print inst           # __str__ allows args to printed directly
...    x, y = inst          # __getitem__ allows args to be unpacked directly
...    print 'x =', x
...    print 'y =', y
...
<type 'exceptions.Exception'>
('spam', 'eggs')
('spam', 'eggs')
x = spam
y = eggs
```

Answer (score 68):

One has pretty much control on which information from the traceback to be displayed/logged when catching exceptions.

The code

```
with open("not_existing_file.txt", 'r') as text:
    pass
```

would produce the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception_checks.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open("not_existing_file.txt", 'r') as text:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'not_existing_file.txt'
```

### Print/Log the full traceback

As others already mentioned, you can catch the whole traceback by using the traceback module:

```
import traceback
try:
    with open("not_existing_file.txt", 'r') as text:
        pass
except Exception as exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

This will produce the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception_checks.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open("not_existing_file.txt", 'r') as text:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'not_existing_file.txt'
```

You can achieve the same by using logging:

```
try:
    with open("not_existing_file.txt", 'r') as text:
        pass
except Exception as exception:
    logger.error(exception, exc_info=True)
```

Output:

```
__main__: 2020-05-27 12:10:47-ERROR- [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'not_existing_file.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception_checks.py", line 27, in <module>
    with open("not_existing_file.txt", 'r') as text:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'not_existing_file.txt'
```

### Print/log error name/message only

You might not be interested in the whole traceback, but only in the most important information, such as Exception name and Exception message, use:

```
try:
    with open("not_existing_file.txt", 'r') as text:
        pass
except Exception as exception:
    print("Exception: {}".format(type(exception).__name__))
    print("Exception message: {}".format(exception))
```

Output:

```
Exception: FileNotFoundError
Exception message: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'not_existing_file.txt'
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer many times, as it's significantly more helpful than the accepted one.

Comment: With the last section in your answer ('Print/log error name\message only') how can I print both `Exception` and `Exception Message` using `print` only once? Whenever I try to do it, it turns out all weird.

Comment: `print(f"Exception: {type(exception).__name__}\nException message: {exception}")`. The `f` at the beginning signifies that it is an `f-string`, which just allows you to put the expression in the curly braces instead of using `.format()`. `f-strings` only work on systems running Python 3.6+ however

Answer (score 38):

Try this

```
try:
    print("Hare Krishna!")
except Exception as er:
    print(er)
```

Comment: Usually a code block with no explanation is not a very good answer. It helps the community much more if you could tell us why we should try this code and why it would/might help the op. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One liner error raising can be done with assert statements if that's what you want to do. This will help you write statically fixable code and check errors early.

```
assert type(A) is type(""), "requires a string"
```

Comment: `assert` statements should not be used for normal logic; they are ignored if python runs with `-O`.  See python(1).

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using a try-except statement. Also, rather than using a print statement, a logging exception logs a message with level ERROR on the logger, which I find is more effective than a print output. This method should only be called from an exception handler, as it is here:

```
import logging

try:
    *code goes here*
except BaseException:
    logging.exception("*Error goes here*")
```

There's good documentation on [this python page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) if you want to learn more about logging and debugging.

Comment: Its difficult to judge in the repl, am I correct in thinking that this prints the exception but does not halt the program? I.e. I can still gracefully exit.