# How do I determine what type of exception occurred?

Tags: python, exception

`some_function()` raises an exception while executing, so the program jumps to the `except`:

```
try:
    some_function()
except:
    print("exception happened!")
```

How do I see what caused the exception to occur?

Comment: Never ever ever use bare `except:` (without a bare `raise`), except *maybe* once per program, and preferably not then.

Comment: If you use multiple `except` clauses you wont need to check the exception type, that is what is usually done to act accordingly to a specific exception type.

Comment: If you care about the type of exception, it's because you've already considered what types of exception might logically occur.

Comment: Inside `except` block the exception is available through [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) function – *This function returns a tuple of three values that give information about the exception that is currently being handled.*

Comment: Related: [How to print an error in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1483429/3357935)

Comment: how do I fill in the blank here?  `except __ as e` . That is, how do I get the class/type in order to catch it? I'm using databricks btw so this is what I see when I try and print `type(e)`: <class 'dbutils.DBUtils.FSHandler.prettify_exception_message.<locals>.f_with_exception_handling.<locals>.ExecutionError'>

Answer (score 588, accepted):

The other answers all point out that you should not catch generic exceptions, but no one seems to want to tell you why, which is essential to understanding when you can break the "rule". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/736029/566644) is an explanation. Basically, it's so that you don't hide:

- the fact that an error occurred
- the specifics of the error that occurred ([error hiding antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding))

So as long as you take care to do none of those things, it's OK to catch the generic exception. For instance, you could provide information about the exception to the user another way, like:

- Present exceptions as dialogs in a GUI
- Transfer exceptions from a worker thread or process to the controlling thread or process in a multithreading or multiprocessing application

So how to catch the generic exception? There are several ways. If you just want the exception object, do it like this:

```
try:
    someFunction()
except Exception as ex:
    template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
    message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
    print message
```

Make *sure* `message` is brought to the attention of the user in a hard-to-miss way! Printing it, as shown above, may not be enough if the message is buried in lots of other messages. Failing to get the users attention is tantamount to swallowing all exceptions, and if there's one impression you should have come away with after reading the answers on this page, it's that this is *not a good thing*. Ending the except block with a `raise` statement will remedy the problem by transparently reraising the exception that was caught.

The difference between the above and using just `except:` without any argument is twofold:

- A bare `except:` doesn't give you the exception object to inspect
- The exceptions `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `GeneratorExit` aren't caught by the above code, which is generally what you want. See the [exception hierarchy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

If you also want the same stacktrace you get if you do not catch the exception, you can get that like this (still inside the except clause):

```
import traceback
print traceback.format_exc()
```

If you use the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module, you can print the exception to the log (along with a message) like this:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger()
log.exception("Message for you, sir!")
```

If you want to dig deeper and examine the stack, look at variables etc., use the [`post_mortem`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#pdb.post_mortem) function of the `pdb` module inside the except block:

```
import pdb
pdb.post_mortem()
```

I've found this last method to be invaluable when hunting down bugs.

Comment: traceback.print_exc() would do the same thing as your more complicated "".join-thing, I think.

Comment: @Gurgeh Yes, but I do not know if he wants to print it or save it to a file or log it or do something else with it.

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but I'd say that's because you should have put a huge fat worning at the beginning saying **You shouldn't need any of this, but here's how it could be done**. And maybe because you suggest to catch the generic Exception.

Comment: @Rik I think you may very well need _all_ of this. For instance, if you have a program with a GUI and a backend, and you want to present all exceptions from the backend as GUI messages instead of having your program quit with a stack trace. In such a case, you should catch the _generic_ Exception, create a traceback text for the dialog, log the exception too, and if in debug mode, enter post-mortem.

Comment: @RikPoggi: Naive thinking. There are many reasonable circumstances when you need to catch exceptions from someone else's code and you don't know what exceptions will be raised.

Comment: This postmortem trick helped me narrow down an exception type of `objc.error` which is sort of a wonky one.

Answer (score 159):

Get the name of the class that exception object belongs:

```
e.__class__.__name__
```

and using print_exc() function will also print stack trace which is essential info for any error message.

Like this:

```
from traceback import print_exc

class CustomException(Exception): pass

try:
    raise CustomException("hi")
except Exception as e:
    print ('type is:', e.__class__.__name__)
    print_exc()
    # print("exception happened!")
```

You will get output like this:

```
type is: CustomException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exc.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise CustomException("hi")
CustomException: hi
```

And after print and analysis, the code can decide not to handle exception and just execute `raise`:

```
from traceback import print_exc

class CustomException(Exception): pass

def calculate():
    raise CustomException("hi")

try:
    calculate()
except CustomException as e:
    # here do some extra steps in case of CustomException
    print('custom logic doing cleanup and more')
    # then re raise same exception
    raise
```

Output:

```
custom logic doing cleanup and more
```

And interpreter prints exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    calculate()
  File "test.py", line 6, in calculate
    raise CustomException("hi")
__main__.CustomException: hi
```

After `raise` original exception continues to propagate further up the call stack. (**Beware of possible pitfall**) If you raise new exception it caries new (shorter) stack trace.

```
from traceback import print_exc

class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, ok):
        self.ok = ok

def calculate():
    raise CustomException(False)

try:
    calculate()
except CustomException as e:
    if not e.ok:
        # Always use `raise` to rethrow exception
        # following is usually mistake, but here we want to stress this point
        raise CustomException(e.ok)
    print("handling exception")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise CustomException(e.message)
__main__.CustomException: hi
```

Notice how traceback does not include `calculate()` function from line `9` which is the origin of original exception `e`.

Comment: If you want to store the traceback as a string, you can use `traceback.format_exc()` as well

Comment: `e.__class__.__name__` is this the same as `type(e).__name__`, as suggested by the answer above?

Comment: @information_interchange yes. The question and accepted answer content changed completely over time. It is shame other participants are not notified by SO machinery :(

Comment: thanks, that error chaining was new to me! Very useful for injecting a new message to HTTP errors.

Comment: Please use `except CustomException` directly and don't check type afterwards.

Comment: @DSchmidt "Don't do it" is not great answer to any question, please see how question is formulated.

Comment: @Alex I'm not answering any questions. I'm just commenting on the current state of this answer. Which uses `if e.__class__ == CustomException` instead of the much cleaner `except CustomException`.

Comment: @DSchmidt the question is: "what *type* of exception occurred?" this is the crux of the answer. If you use `except CustomException` there is no question what *type* of exception is it, because its hardcoded. The `.__class__` is what one learns from this answer.

Comment: @Alex and your first example answers that question reasonably well. Your other examples showing the raise and logging differences should showcase the correct `except` IMHO. People copy this.

Comment: @DSchmidt you are on point

Answer (score 16):

You usually should not catch all possible exceptions with `try: ... except` as this is overly broad. Just catch those that are expected to happen for whatever reason. If you really must, for example if you want to find out more about some problem while debugging, you should do

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as ex:
    print ex # do whatever you want for debugging.
    raise    # re-raise exception.
```

Comment: The use of the word "never" here has never been so wrong. I use `try: ... except Exception:` around lots of things, e.g. usage of network dependent libraries, or a data masseuse that may get weird stuff sent to her. Naturally I have proper logging too. This is crucial to allow the program to continue operating in the case of a single mistake in input data.

Comment: Ever tried to catch all the exceptions that could be raised when sending a email using `smtplib`?

Comment: There may be some special cases where catching all exceptions is necessary, but on a general level you should just catch what you expect so you don't accidentally hide errors that you did not anticipate. Good logging is a good idea, too, of course.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable to catch all exceptions. If you are calling a third-party library, you may not know what exceptions will be raised in that library. In such a case, the only recourse is to catch all the exceptions, for example to log them in a file.

Comment: Ok ok you're right, I'll rephrase my answer to make clear that there are valid use cases for a catch all.

Comment: Why is the re-raising necessary? To crash the program deliberately?

Comment: Because re-raising it will not hide the exception, you just want to print it out for debugging purposes before you continue the program unchanged.

Answer (score 13):

Most answers point to `except (…) as (…):` syntax (rightly so) but at the same time nobody wants to talk about an elephant in the room, where the elephant is `sys.exc_info()` function.
From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) of *sys* module (emphasis mine):

> This function returns a tuple of three values that give information
>   about the exception that is currently being handled.
>   (…)
>   If no exception is being handled anywhere on the stack, a tuple
>   containing three None values is returned. Otherwise, the values
>   returned are (type, value, traceback). Their meaning is: **type gets the
>   type of the exception being handled** (a subclass of BaseException);
>   value gets the exception instance (an instance of the exception type);
>   traceback gets a traceback object (see the Reference Manual) which
>   encapsulates the call stack at the point where the exception
>   originally occurred.

I think the `sys.exc_info()` could be treated as the most direct answer to the original question of *How do I know what type of exception occurred?*

Comment: That's the correct answer to me as it does solve the problem of what exception is occurring so what should I put instead of bare `except`. Just for the sake of completeness, `exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]` will tell you the exception type which can then be used on the `except`.

Answer (score 10):

These answers are fine for debugging, but for programmatically testing the exception, `isinstance(e, SomeException)` can be handy, as it tests for subclasses of `SomeException` too, so you can create functionality that applies to hierarchies of exceptions.

Answer (score 8):

Unless `somefunction` is a very bad coded legacy function, you shouldn't need what you're asking.

Use multiple `except` clause to handle in different ways different exceptions:

```
try:
    someFunction()
except ValueError:
    # do something
except ZeroDivision:
    # do something else
```

The main point is that you shouldn't catch generic exception, but only the ones that you need to. I'm sure that you don't want to shadow unexpected errors or bugs.

Comment: If you are using a third-party library, you may not know what exceptions will be raised inside of it. How can you possibly catch all of them individually?

Answer (score 7):

In Python 2, the following are useful

```
except Exception, exc:

    # This is how you get the type
    excType = exc.__class__.__name__

    # Here we are printing out information about the Exception
    print 'exception type', excType
    print 'exception msg', str(exc)

    # It's easy to reraise an exception with more information added to it
    msg = 'there was a problem with someFunction'
    raise Exception(msg + 'because of %s: %s' % (excType, exc))
```

Comment: -1 as using `exc.__class__.__name__` had been already suggested in Alex's answer – https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824060/95735

Answer (score 4):

Use `type` class and `as` statement

```
try:#code
except Exception as e:
     m=type(e)
     #m is the class of the exception
     strm=str(m)
     #strm is the string of m
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help a little more

```
import sys
varExcepHandling, varExcepHandlingZer = 2, 0
try:
  print(varExcepHandling/varExcepHandlingZer)
except Exception as ex: 
  print(sys.exc_info())
```

'`sys.exc_info()`' will return a tuple, if you only want the exception class name use '`sys.exc_info()[0]`'

Note:- if you want to see all the exception classes just write `dir(__builtin__)`

Comment: only response one that answers the actual question

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'm handling my exceptions.  The idea is to do try solving the issue if that's easy, and later add a more desirable solution if possible.  Don't solve the issue in the code that generates the exception, or that code loses track of the original algorithm, which should be written to-the-point.  However, pass what data is needed to solve the issue, and return a lambda just in case you can't solve the problem outside of the code that generates it.

```
path = 'app.p'

def load():
    if os.path.exists(path):
        try:
            with open(path, 'rb') as file:
                data = file.read()
                inst = pickle.load(data)
        except Exception as e:
            inst = solve(e, 'load app data', easy=lambda: App(), path=path)()
    else:
        inst = App()
    inst.loadWidgets()

# e.g. A solver could search for app data if desc='load app data'
def solve(e, during, easy, **kwargs):
    class_name = e.__class__.__name__
    print(class_name + ': ' + str(e))
    print('\t during: ' + during)
    return easy
```

For now, since I don't want to think tangentially to my app's purpose, I haven't added any complicated solutions.  But in the future, when I know more about possible solutions (since the app is designed more), I could add in a dictionary of solutions indexed by `during`.

In the example shown, one solution might be to look for app data stored somewhere else, say if the 'app.p' file got deleted by mistake.

For now, since writing the exception handler is not a smart idea (we don't know the best ways to solve it yet, because the app design will evolve), we simply return the easy fix which is to act like we're running the app for the first time (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

To add to Lauritz's answer, I created a decorator/wrapper for exception handling and the wrapper logs which type of exception occurred.

```
class general_function_handler(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return self.__class__(self.func.__get__(obj, type))
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            retval = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, e :
            logging.warning('Exception in %s' % self.func)
            template = "An exception of type {0} occured. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(e).__name__, e.args)
            logging.exception(message)
            sys.exit(1) # exit on all exceptions for now
        return retval
```

This can be called on a class method or a standalone function with the decorator:

@general_function_handler

See my blog about for the full example: http://ryaneirwin.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/python-decorators-and-exception-handling/

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, may be it will help you:

```
try:
  t
except Exception as e:
  print(type(e))
```

Output:

```
<class 'NameError'>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can start as Lauritz recommended, with:

```
except Exception as ex:
```

and then just to `print ex` like so:

```
try:
    #your try code here
except Exception as ex:
    print ex
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit so your answer stands alone?

Comment: sure: you can print the caught exception like this: 
try:
    #your try code here
except Exception as ex:
    print ex

now the error will be printed

Answer (score -2):

Your question is: "How can I see exactly what happened in the someFunction() that caused the exception to happen?"

It seems to me that you are not asking about how to handle unforeseen exceptions in production code (as many answers assumed), but how to find out what is causing a particular exception during development.

The easiest way is to use a debugger that can stop where the uncaught exception occurs, preferably not exiting, so that you can inspect the variables. For example, PyDev in the Eclipse open source IDE can do that. To enable that in Eclipse, open the Debug perspective, select `Manage Python Exception Breakpoints` in the `Run` menu, and check `Suspend on uncaught exceptions`.

Answer (score -3):

The actual exception can be captured in the following way:

```
try:
    i = 1/0
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

You can learn more about exceptions from [The Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score -4):

**Use the below for both Exception type and Exception text**

```
import sys
print(str(sys.exc_info()[0]).split(' ')[1].strip('>').strip("'")+"-"+(str(sys.exc_info()[1])))
```

**if you want only exception type: Use -->**

```
import sys
print(str(sys.exc_info()[0]).split(' ')[1].strip('>').strip("'"))
```

**Thanks Rajeshwar**

Answer (score -5):

Just refrain from catching the exception and the traceback that Python prints will tell you what exception occurred.