# Convert exception error to string

Tags: python

I want to work with the error message from an exception but can't seem to convert it to a string.  I've read the os library man page but something is not clicking for me.

Printing the error works:

```
try:
    os.open("test.txt", os.O_RDONLY)
except OSError as err:
    print ("I got this error: ", err)
```

But this does not:

```
try:
    os.open("test.txt", os.O_RDONLY)
except OSError as err:
    print ("I got this error: " + err)

TypeError: Can't convert 'FileNotFoundError' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From [the docs for `print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream

So in the first case, your error is converted to a string by the `print` built-in, whereas no such conversion takes place when you just try and concatenate your error to a string. So, to replicate the behavior of passing the message and the error as separate arguments, you must convert your error to a string with [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).

Comment: Therefore wrapping err in str() as in str(err) works.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that it only "prints" the error message but not the error type. How do we print both the type and message in short code, just like Python does it?

Comment: @HendyIrawan Multiple approaches, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824050/4686625

Answer (score 104):

In my experience what you want is [`repr(err)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr), which will return both the exception type and the message.

[`str(err)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) only gives the message.

Comment: This is a much more useful answer, although it'll only work if you are doing debugging/don't already know what you're catching for.