# Separating except portion of a try/except into a function

Tags: python, try-except

I have a try/except where I repeat the except portion frequently in my code. This led me to believe that it would be better to separate the except portion into a function.

Below is my use case:

```
try:
  ...
except api.error.ReadError as e:
  ...
except api.error.APIConnectionError as e:
  ...
except Exception as e:
  ...
```

How would I go about separating this logic into a function so I can do something as simple as:

```
try:
  ...
except:
  my_error_handling_function(e)
```

Comment: How about making a custom error class so you can just catch a single kind of error?

Comment: You don't have to catch each exception separately if they are handled the same: `except (api.error.ReadError, api.error.APIConnectionError, Exception) as e:` If they aren't handled the same, don't use one function to handle them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the function:

```
def my_error_handling(e):
    #Do stuff
```

...and pass in the `exception` object as the parameter:

```
try:
    #some code
except Exception as e:
    my_error_handling(e)
```

Using just a generic `Exception` type will allow you to have a single `except` clause and handle and test for different error types within your handling function.

In order to check for the name of the caught exception, you can get it by doing:

```
type(e).__name__
```

Which will print the name, such as `ValueError`, `IOError`, etc.

Comment: I understand this part, but I'm not sure what my_error_handling(e) would look like within the context of my 3 use cases

Comment: @MichaelSmith you simply do `if` statements to check like `if type(e).__name__ == 'ReadError'`

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Will give it a try soon.

Answer (score 0):

Define your function:

```
def my_error_handling(e):
    #Handle exception
```

And do what you're proposing:

```
try:
  ...
except Exception as e:
  my_error_handling_function(e)
```

You can handle logic by getting the type of the exception 'e' within your function.  See: [python: How do I know what type of exception occurred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823936/python-how-do-i-know-what-type-of-exception-occured)

Comment: You're try/except is not catch is not assigning any value `e` to pass, nor any specified `Exception` type

Comment: But at this point how would my_error_handling function know what logic to execute for the 3 different cases of exceptions?

Comment: @MichaelSmith I updated my post to include that checking

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include definition for e.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest refactoring your code so the try/except block is only present in a single location.

For instance, an API class with a `send()` method, seems like a reasonable candidate for containing the error handling logic you have described in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like try-catch statement, you can use [exception-decouple](https://github.com/cfytrok/exception-decouple) package and decorator.

```py
from exception_decouple import redirect_exceptions

def my_error_handling(arg, e):
    #Do stuff

@redirect_exceptions(my_error_handling, api.error.ReadError, api.error.APIConnectionError)
def foo(arg):
    ...
```