# Handle a specific exception (say, ENOENT) separately from others

Tags: python, exception

In Python, specific POSIX error conditions do not have their separate exception types — they are distinguished by an attribute inside of the `OSError` exception object.

Let's imagine I'm performing a file operation (removing a possibly inexistent file over SFTP) and I want to ignore ENOENT, but still handle any other error or exception. Is it possible to do that more elegantly than as following?

```
try:
    action()
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
        pass
    else:
        sophisticated_error_handling(e)
except e:
    sophisticated_error_handling(e)
```

I dislike this method because it involves repetition.

*Note: there is no X-Y problem. The "action" is a library function and it cannot be told to ignore ENOENT.*

Comment: catch all errors and check the type in the if statement? Not sure how exactly, but pseudocode: `try: somecode except e: if e.type == OSError and e.errno == errno.ENOENT: pass / else: sophisticated()`

Comment: Example: https://repl.it/JnUQ/0  with a caveat of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824050/478656

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a shorter, and more idiomatic way of achieving the same result than the code you propose.

You do try/catch for the error you anticipate, and then check the condition on the error object inside the except clause. The trick is to re-raise the same error object unchanged if the error object is not of the particular sub-type you were expecting.

```
import errno
try:
    action()
except IOError as ioe:
    if ioe.errno not in (errno.ENOENT,):
        # this re-raises the same error object.
        raise
    pass # ENOENT. that line is optional, but it makes it look
         # explicit and intentional to fall through the exception handler.
```

It's important that you re-raise the initial error with just `raise`, without parameters. You may be tempted re-raise with `raise ioe` instead of just `raise` on that line. Even though you would preserve the same error message, if you used `raise ioe` it would make the error's stack trace look as if the error happened on that line, and not inside `action()` where it really happened.

In your proposed code, your second exception handler (i.e. `except e`), even though it is syntactically valid, will not trigger. You have to specify `except <type>:`, or `except <type> as <variable>:`.

If you wanted to do additional sophisticated error handling, to ensure correctness, you could nest all of the previous try/catch in an outer `try`/`except`:

```
try:
    try:
        action()
    except IOError as ioe:
        if ioe.errno not in (errno.ENOENT,): raise
except IOError as any_other_ioerror:
    # this is reached in case you get other errno values
    sophisticated_error_handling()
except OtherExceptionTypeICareAbout as other:
    other_fancy_handler()
```

One thing you want to be mindful of, when nesting exception handlers like that, is that exception handlers can raise exceptions too. There's a tutorial on exception handling in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html), but you may find it a bit dense.

**Method #2**

If you're into meta-python tricks, you could consider an approach using the [with statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with). You could create a python context manager which absorbs particular types of errors.

```
# add this to your utilities
class absorb(object):
    def __init__(self, *codes):
        self.codes = codes
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, value, traceback):
        if hasattr(value, "errno") and getattr(value, "errno") in self.codes:
            return True # exception is suppressed
        return False # exception is re-raised
    def __enter__(self):
        return None
```

And then you can write simple code like:

```
# if ENOENT occurs during the block, abort the block, but do not raise.
with absorb(errno.ENOENT):
    delete_my_file_whether_it_exists_or_not()
    print("file deleted.") # reachable only if previous call returned
```

If you still want to have sophisticated error handling for other errno cases, you would include the above in a try/except, like so:

```
try:
    with absorb(errno.ENOENT): action()
    # the code here is reachable only if action() returns,
    # or if one of the suppressed/absorbed exceptions has been raised (i.e. ENOENT)
except IOError as any_other_ioerror:
    # any exception with errno != ENOENT will come here
    sophisticated_error_handling()
```

*Note: you may also want to take a look at [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html), which might eliminate some of the meta-gore for you.*

Comment: Thanks, I know how to re-raise an exception. I actually specifically wanted to avoid double-try-catch, because it looks ugly. However, I love meta-programming and I do like your "Method #2" very much — thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Next by the except just enter the error type!

```
test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'aasd']
for  i in range(50):
   try:
      print(test[i])
except IndexError:
   pass
```