# Python : How to get exception code using Exception Handling in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am using exception handling in `python-2.7`. I am getting exception message like `UNIQUE constraint failed: table.name` but someone tell me how to get exception error code like `3`   /* Access permission denied */?

```
try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO `table` ('name','contact') VALUES(?,?)",
                ('name', 'contact',))
    con.commit()
except Exception as ex:
    print str(ex)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: How do I know what type of exception occurred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823936/python-how-do-i-know-what-type-of-exception-occurred)

Comment: without printing str(ex) that will never work , because python can't concernate with object or str

Answer (score 0):

```
print (ex.message)
```

It is good for me.