# Python - How to catch read() errors reading files

Tags: python, file

In this code i am checking for an error when trying to open the file but how can i also check for an error when reading the file?

```
try:
    with open("file.txt") as f:
        contents = f.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File Not Found")
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open , https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824050/797495

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple except statements. So just add another one after your current except for the error that you want to deal with this time.