# What are ALL of the exceptions that pandas.read_csv() throw?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What are all the exceptions that can be thrown by pd.read_csv()?

In the example below I am capturing some exception types explicitly and using a generic Exception to catch the others, but what are the others exactly?

Reviewing the [documentation for pandas read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) I can't see a complete list of exceptions thrown.

In a more general case, what is the recommended practice to determine all of the types of exceptions that can be thrown by any call/library?

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found.")
except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
    print("No data")
except pd.errors.ParserError:
    print("Parse error")
except Exception:
    print("Some other exception")
```

Comment: I think it's important to ask yourself why you want to do this and whether it adds value to whatever you're doing.

Comment: You can look here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/parsers.py#L549-L717 , but I'm not sure why you would want to to do this.

Comment: I see some highly ranked answers for other questions such as this one which recommend against capturing generic exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824050/833960. They seem to imply that I should try to determine what exceptions could be thrown, I guess that is what I am asking.

Comment: My use case – a pipeline, where you can import CSV file, select columns, modify values, and create visualisations, export it to another format like xlsx. Let's say a user will send an excel file but with `.csv` extension. I would like to check if this is an eligible file to process considering content, encodings, separators, etc. Without the knowledge about the error, I would be forced to show a user very generic message.

Comment: @DavidErickson you should use `Copy permalink` when linking to files from VCS repositories. The link is dead now. Here is the current link that will show the `to_csv` version at the time of posting unless the repo is cleaned: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/00af20a22c6c64ad2d8f48345beaede0e946d630/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L1056

Answer (score 3):

You can see all the exceptions in the following file:

```
Python > 3.8 > lib > python > site-packages > pandas > errors > __init__.py
```

BTW, the exceptions are:

- IntCastingNaNError
- NullFrequencyError
- PerformanceWarning
- UnsupportedFunctionCall
- ParserError
- DtypeWarning
- EmptyDataError
- ParserWarning
- MergeError
- AccessorRegistrationWarning
- AbstractMethodError

Answer (score 2):

If you import `pandas` and use the `dir` function you can view all exceptions. Exceptions are contained in the [`pandas.errors`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/general_utility_functions.html#exceptions-and-warnings) submodule.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: ([e for e in dir(pd.errors) if "__" not in e])
Out[2]: 
['AbstractMethodError',
'AccessorRegistrationWarning',
'DtypeWarning',
'DuplicateLabelError',
'EmptyDataError',
'IntCastingNaNError',
'InvalidIndexError',
'MergeError',
'NullFrequencyError',
'NumbaUtilError',
'OptionError',
'OutOfBoundsDatetime',
'OutOfBoundsTimedelta',
'ParserError',
'ParserWarning',
'PerformanceWarning',
'UnsortedIndexError',
'UnsupportedFunctionCall']
```

You can use these for exception handling. As an example, see below

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

bad_date = datetime.date(22, 10, 4)

try:
    pd.to_datetime(bad_date)
except pd.errors.OutOfBoundsDatetime as e:
    # do some error handling here 
    # or raise the error
    print("there was a bad date")
    raise e
```

Answer (score 1):

A complete list and explanation can be found in the pandas [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/00af20a22c6c64ad2d8f48345beaede0e946d630/pandas/errors/__init__.py)

Answer (score -8):

This is a way to catch all exceptions:

```
import sys

try:
    int("test") # creates a ValueError
except BaseException as e:
    print('The exception: {}'.format(e))
```

If you really want to find out the possible exceptions of read_csv you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/601eff1768380313ec452ba8677cc7e825706796/pandas/io/parsers.py#L545)

Comment: https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/

Comment: This is a very bad practice, you would also capture Exceptions you are not supposed to.

Comment: The problem is not that you will catch all exceptions, the problem is not logging after catching all exceptions.