# Python Error Handling: finally vs. new line dedented

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch-finally

When using `try` and `except` for error handling, does it matter whether you explicitly call `finally` or if you simply go to a new line that is dedented from the exception code? For example, is there any circumstance under which the two functions below will produce different results?

```
#Function 1 with finally
def final(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)

    except:
        print("Error")

    finally:
        print("End Function")


#Function 2 with new line dedent
def dedent(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)

    except:
        print("Error")

    print("End Function")
```

**Update:**
Thanks for the explanation of `finally` running even if there is an error in the `except` block. One additional thing I wanted to point out is that the `finally` block will run even if you return an object within the except block. For example, function 3 below will print even after the `return` while function 4 will not.

```
#Function 3 with finally
def final(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)

    except:
        return 3

    finally:
        print("End Function 3")


#Function 4 with new line dedent
def dedent(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)

    except:
        return 3

    print("End Function 4")

test1 = final('test')
test2 = dedent('test')
```

Comment: Your example is very trivial to understand the usage. Look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11552007/1628832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the error in the `except` block that's been mentioned already:

```
def final(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)

    except:
        print("Error")
        damnit

    finally:
        print("End Function")

def dedent(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)

    except:
        print("Error")
        damnit

    print("End Function")

try:
    final("a")
except Exception as e:
    print("There was an error:", e)
#>>> Error
#>>> End Function
#>>> There was an error: global name 'damnit' is not defined

try:
    dedent("a")
except Exception as e:
    print("There was an error:", e)
#>>> Error
#>>> There was an error: global name 'damnit' is not defined
```

There's also `return` behaviour:

```
def final(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)

    except:
        print("Error")
        return "Return inside"

    finally:
        print("End Function")
        return "Return outside"

def dedent(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)

    except:
        print("Error")
        return "Return inside"

    print("End Function")
    return "Return outside"

try:
    final("a")
except Exception as e:
    print("There was an error:", e)
#>>> Error
#>>> End Function
#>>> 'Return outside'

try:
    dedent("a")
except Exception as e:
    print("There was an error:", e)
#>>> Error
#>>> 'Return inside'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `return` behavior, I just noticed that as well while playing with my code.

Answer (score 1):

The first version will still run the `finally:` suite even when the `except` handler raises a *new* exception. In the second version, the final `print()` will *not* be executed in that case:

```
>>> def print(*args, **kw):
...     if not args or args[0] != 'End Function':
...         raise ValueError("Only print End Function!")
...     __builtins__.print(*args, **kw)
... 
>>> final(0)
End Function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in final
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in print
ValueError: Only print End Function!

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in final
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in print
ValueError: Only print End Function!
>>> dedent(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in dedent
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in print
ValueError: Only print End Function!

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in dedent
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in print
ValueError: Only print End Function!
```

Note that the *first* thing printed in `final(0)` is `End Function`; no such text is printed for `dedent(0)`.

You never need to explicitly execute a `finally:` suite; it is **always** run, even if you were to exit the function early with `return`, or break out of a loop with `break` or use `continue` to skip the rest of the loop body:

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         print("In an infinite loop?")
...         break
...     finally:
...         print("Executed before the loop ends")
... 
In an infinite loop
Executed before the loop ends
```

Quoting from the [`try` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> If `finally` is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The `try` clause is executed, including any `except` and `else` clauses. If an exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the exception is temporarily saved. The `finally` clause is executed. If there is a saved exception it is re-raised at the end of the `finally` clause.

and

> When a `return`, `break` or `continue` statement is executed in the `try` suite of a `try`...`finally` statement, the `finally` clause is also executed ‘on the way out.’

Answer (score 1):

According to [PEP 341](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0341/):

> ```
> try:
>     block-1 ...
> except Exception1:
>     handler-1 ...
> except Exception2:
>     handler-2 ...
> else:
>     else-block
> finally:
>     final-block
> ```
>
> The code in block-1 is executed. If the code raises an exception, the
>   various except blocks are tested: if the exception is of class
>   Exception1, handler-1 is executed; otherwise if it's of class
>   Exception2, handler-2 is executed, and so forth. If no exception is
>   raised, the else-block is executed.
>
> No matter what happened previously, the final-block is executed once
>   the code block is complete and any raised exceptions handled. Even if
>   there's an error in an exception handler or the else-block and a new
>   exception is raised, the code in the final-block is still run.

So as Martjin said, the code in finally will be executed even if the `except` raises another another error.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is clear if exceptions are raised all over the place.

If only the try block raises an error then they are the same.

```
#Function 1 with finally
def final(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)
        raise Exception
    except:
        print("Error")    
    finally:
        print("End Function")


#Function 2 with new line dedent
def dedent(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)
        raise Exception
    except:
        print("Error")    
    print("End Function")

final(10)
dedent(10)
```

However. If the except block also raises an error, then the finally block is guaranteed to run.

```
#Function 1 with finally
def final(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)
        raise Exception
    except:
        print("Error")
        raise Exception
    finally:
        print("This will be printed")

#Function 2 with new line dedent
def dedent(x):
    try:
        print(x*x)
        raise Exception
    except:
        print("Error")
        raise Exception
    print("This will not be printed")
final(10)
dedent(10)
```