# Print error type, error statement and own statement

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to try a statement and if there is an error, I want it to print the original error it receives, but also add my own statement to it.

I was looking for this answer, found something that was almost complete [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483429/how-to-print-an-error-in-python).

The following code did almost all I wanted (I'm using Python 2 so it works):

```
except Exception, e: 
    print str(e)
```

This way I can print the error message and the string I wanted myself, however it does not print the error type (`IOError`, `NameError`, etc.). What I want is for it to print the exact same message it would normally do (so `ErrorType: ErrorString`) plus my own statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print the exception information, you can use the `traceback` module:

```
import traceback
try:
    infinity = 1 / 0
except Exception as e:
    print "PREAMBLE"
    traceback.print_exc()
    print "POSTAMBLE, I guess"
```

This gives you:

```
PREAMBLE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testprog.py", line 3, in <module>
    infinity = 1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
POSTAMBLE, I guess
```

You can also rethrow the exception without `traceback` but, since it's an exception being thrown, you can't do anything afterwards:

```
try:
    infinity = 1 / 0
except Exception as e:
    print "PREAMBLE"
    raise
    print "POSTAMBLE, I guess"
```

Note the lack of `POSTAMBLE` in this case:

```
PREAMBLE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testprog.py", line 2, in <module>
    infinity = 1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: Ah, that is even easier indeed. 

I think my ideal scenario would be if I can print my own statement behind the error message, since it is more readable this way. But I also figured that when raising, you can't do anything after. So unless there is an easy way to extract the whole error message (including traceback) I think your answer is the best I can do :)

Thanks!

Comment: Just a note though: Since you are now not using the error string 'e' in your except clause, can't you just change "except Exception as e:" to "except:" now?

Answer (score 0):

From [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

```
try:
    raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
except Exception as inst:
    print(type(inst))    # the exception instance
    print(inst.args)     # arguments stored in .args
    print(inst)          # __str__ allows args to be printed directly,
```

Will be print:

```
<type 'exceptions.Exception'>
('spam', 'eggs')
('spam', 'eggs')
```