# adding file to start up of windows 8.1 uisng python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a following code which adds a particular file to startup of windows

```
userName = getpass.getuser()
filePath = 'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' %userName


if os.path.exists(filePath):
    if os.path.isfile(filePath + 'l.exe') == False:
        try:
            shutil.copy2(sys.argv[0], filePath + 'l.exe')
        except:
            pass
```

but this is not adding the file to start up ..
I dont understand why ..
can anyone plz help me..

Comment: you may debug it and get a better idea about what's happening. check the path. you may want to use os.path.join().

Comment: C:\Users\GhOsT\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\l.exe

I got this when i used print os.path.join(filePath + 'l.exe')

Comment: Can you please check C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ there may be a .exe file as per your script

Comment: no sir nothing in the start up folder

Comment: name 'shutil' is not defined what error is this

Comment: sorry guys , i forgot to import shutil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if userName is `abc`, filePath will be `C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, `filePath + 'l.exe'` will be `C:\Users\abc\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startupl.exe` -- you should find the issue now, right?

I would sugguest to use `os.path.join(filePath, 'l.exe')` and don't just `pass` an exeception, at least you want to print out the exception to get the details. 
[How to print an error in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483429/how-to-print-an-error-in-python)

Comment: filePath = 'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\\' %userName

Comment: i have written this, yet no change

Comment: Thank u  very much