# How to print an exception in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, web-scraping

Right now, I catch the exception in the `except Exception:` clause, and do `print(exception)`. The result provides no information since it always prints `<class 'Exception'>`. I knew this used to work in python 2, but how do I do it in python3?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, what is bound to the name `exception` exactly? Please post the snippet where this behavior appears and most importanly the part where the name `exception` is initialized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print an exception in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483429/how-do-i-print-an-exception-in-python)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I'm guessing that you need to assign the `Exception` to a variable. As [shown in the Python 3 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

```py
def fails():
    x = 1 / 0

try:
    fails()
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

To give a brief explanation, `as` is a pseudo-assignment keyword used in certain compound statements to assign or alias the preceding statement to a variable.

In this case, `as` assigns the caught exception to a variable allowing for information about the exception to stored and used later, instead of needing to be dealt with immediately.

(This is discussed in detail in the [Python 3 Language Reference: The `try` Statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement).)

---

There are other compound statements that use `as`. The first is the `with` statement:

```py
@contextmanager
def opening(filename):
    f = open(filename)
    try:
        yield f
    finally:
        f.close()

with opening(filename) as f:
    # ...read data from f...
```

Here, `with` statements are used to wrap the execution of a block with methods defined by [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers). This functions like an extended `try...except...finally` statement in a neat generator package, and the `as` statement assigns the generator-produced result from the context manager to a variable for extended use.

(This is discussed in detail in the [Python 3 Language Reference: The `with` Statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).)

---

As of Python 3.10, `match` statements also use `as`:

```py
from random import randint

match randint(0, 2):
    case 0|1 as low:
        print(f"{low} is a low number")
    case _:
        print("not a low number")
```

`match` statements take an expression (in this case, `randint(0, 2)`) and compare its value to each `case` branch one at a time until one of them succeeds, at which point it executes that branch's block. In a `case` branch, `as` can be used to assign the value of the branch to a variable if that branch succeeds. If it doesn't succeed, it is not bound.

(The `match` statement is covered by the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements) and discussed in detail in the [Python 3 Language Reference: `match` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-match-statement).)

---

Finally, `as` can be used when importing modules, to alias a module to a different (usually shorter) name:

```py
import foo.bar.baz as fbb
```

This is discussed in detail in the [Python 3 Language Reference: The `import` Statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import).

Answer (score 31):

These are the changes since python 2:

```py
    try:
        1 / 0
    except Exception as e: # (as opposed to except Exception, e:)
                           # ^ that will just look for two classes, Exception and e
        # for the repr
        print(repr(e))
        # for just the message, or str(e), since print calls str under the hood
        print(e)
        # the arguments that the exception has been called with. 
        # the first one is usually the message. (OSError is different, though)
        print(e.args)
```

You can look into the standard library module [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback) for fancier stuff.

Comment: Python 3 has no `message` attribute, it seems, and `str(e)` prepends the location and type of the error to the message; correct?

Comment: maybe late, but just for clearance... str(e) appear to return just the message in python 3, ie: 'name 're' is not defined'

Answer (score 20):

Try

```
try:
    print(undefined_var)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

this will print the representation given by `e.__str__()`:

> "name 'undefined_var' is not defined"

you can also use:

```
print(repr(e))
```

which will include the Exception class name:

> "NameError("name 'undefined_var' is not defined",)"

Answer (score 5):

Here is the way I like that prints out all of the error stack.

```
import logging

try:
    1 / 0
except Exception as _e:
    # any one of the follows:
    # print(logging.traceback.format_exc())
    logging.error(logging.traceback.format_exc())
```

The output looks as the follows:

```
ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/PATH-TO-YOUR/filename.py", line 4, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

`LOGGING_FORMAT` :

```
LOGGING_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s\n  File "%(pathname)s", line %(lineno)d\n  %(levelname)s [%(message)s]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Although if you want a code that is compatible with both **python2** and **python3** you can use this:

```
import logging
try:
    1/0
except Exception as e:
    if hasattr(e, 'message'):
        logging.warning('python2')
        logging.error(e.message)
    else:
        logging.warning('python3')
        logging.error(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

[In Python3]

Let's say you want to handle an `IndexError` and print the traceback, you can do the following:

```
from traceback import print_tb 
empty_list = [] 
try: 
    x = empty_list[100]
except IndexError as index_error: 
    print_tb(index_error.__traceback__)
```

Note: You can use the `format_tb` function instead of `print_tb` to get the traceback as a string for logging purposes. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use print(e), since that won't print a stack trace, which is a nightmare for debugging.  traceback.print_exception is what you're looking for:

```
import traceback
try:
    assert False
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exception(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've use this :

```
except (socket.timeout, KeyboardInterrupt) as e:
    logging.debug("Exception : {}".format(str(e.__str__).split(" ")[3]))
    break
```

Let me know if it does not work for you !!

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
with self.assertRaisesMessage(ValueError, 'invalid literal for int()'):
  int('a')
```

[Reference](http://with%20self.assertRaisesMessage(Exception,%20%22User%20does%20not%20exist%22,%20):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.team.activate_member(member_email))