# How do i know which argument has error message when resolving exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, sqlalchemy, python-2.x

I am trying to resolve exceptions. In python2, i used to write like this:

```
        except (Exception,InternalError,SQLAlchemyError) as e:
        message = e.message;
```

But in python3 it gives an error that attribute message is not found. Now i tried this:

```
        except (Exception,InternalError,SQLAlchemyError) as e:
        message = e[0]
```

But how do I know which argument e[0], e[1] etc of the exception will hold the message? i need only the message and not all the arguments of the exception.

Comment: Use `isinstance`. But maybe if you need to differentiate between these different types of exceptions, they should not be part of the same except block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print an exception in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596810/how-to-print-an-exception-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `e.message`, python3 now has `e.args` which is a tuple of args. This allows developers to return multiple arguments. However if only one argument is passed then essentially `e.message` is equivalent to `e.args[0]`

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.args)

Comment: e.args[0] usually contains the message but not necessarily, it may some other information regarding the exception. That is where the issue lies

Comment: @HarrisMuzaffar True, but `e.args[0]` will usually have the most important info and most errors/exceptions only pass one argument. As for this with multiple arguments, `str(e)` essentially concatenates them into a string with some minor formatting.