# What's the right way to format a python exception message that is compatible with Python2 and Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, error-handling, exception

Suppose I have an exception `e`, and I would like to format it for logging/printing:

```
def format_exception(e):
    # type: (Exception) -> Text
    """Log formatter used in a catch-all near the edge."""
    return str(e)  # Python 2.7 only
```

Specifically, I want to get the exception message - the equivalent of `e.message` in Python 2.6, or `str(e)` in Python 2.7.

I have tried

```
return six_text_type(e)
```

However, that fails if `e.message` contains encoded bytes (which, given that I am working in a py2-py3 environment, can happen.)

```
>>> six.text_type(MyError(u''))   # OK
>>> six.text_type(MyError(u''.encode('utf-8')))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

`traceback.format_exception_only` (from [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483429/how-to-print-an-error-in-python)) does almost the right thing (handles both bytes and unicode), but it forces me to split on `:`. It also doesn't help that `format_exception_only` returns a byte string in python2, and a unicode string in python3.

```
# python2
>>> type(traceback.format_exception_only(type(e), e)[0])
str
# python3
>>> type(traceback.format_exception_only(type(e), e)[0])
str
```

So that doesn't quite work. Wrapping that in `six.text_type` again fails if `e.message` contains encoded bytes.

What's the right way to fill in `format_exception`? Do I really need to use `traceback2`?

```
def format_exception(e):
    # type: (Exception) -> Text
    return traceback2.format_exception_only(type(e), e)[0].split(': ')[1]
```

I can install and use `traceback2`, but it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: I just don't bother with using `six.text_type` - if your code base **must** work under both Python 2 AND Python 3 at the same time, the only way I found reliability is to always prefix human text strings with `u''` and things that are to be `bytes` with `b''`.  Don't bother with `six.text_type` because it adds complexity that makes it not work mixing across so many API boundaries (logging/printing/error handling/stack traces).

Comment: I found using `u''` and `b''` explicitly to work best as well. However, in this case I am getting `e` from some faraway place, and I just need to log it.

Comment: How does that faraway `e` is produced?  Will calling `str(e)` under Python3 always work and calling `unicode(e)` under Python 2 also works?  If that's the case I just force `str = unicode` under a Python 2 environment and forget about it.  If that exception is produced through certain heuristics on the running Python environment, that may get tricky because that's premature optimization on the library's part.

Comment: Could be produced by 3rd party libraries, such as one that validates email addresses which may (as of recently) contain emojis. `unicode(e)` doesn't always work if your exception contains encoded bytes e.g. `unicode(Exception(u''.encode('utf-8')))`. The issue here is that different 3rd parties don't follow the same unicode-vs-bytes convention.

Comment: The approach I was going to suggest to deal with the gaggle of types (of both `bytes` and `str`) would have been something similar to what `traceback2` does, basically every non-ascii characters will simply be rendered as `\x` escaped representation, i.e. `[u"Exception: b'\\xe2\\x80\\xa2'\n"]`. Python 2 forces a lot of unhealthy habits because zero distinction between human readable text and raw bytes, resulting in the **internal API** being completely inconsistent with how those types are handled (manifests in stdlib breakages).  I can't wait till Python 2 is completely dropped everywhere.

Comment: Basically: there is no better way - the only way to do this is to do exactly what `traceback2` does, because `traceback` is broken in Python 2 (along with `StringIO`, `logging`, and any stdlib that uses `str` and/or `unicode` types wrongly)