# Transforming pose with tf listener is not working in Rviz

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, ros

I have set some fixed position and orientation (pose) values to PR2's head_plate_frame in Rviz, trying to transform pose from head_plate_frame to base_link frame and save the values in position and quaternion arrays. But instead of going to try block, the except block is being executed, anyone can help? What is the bug here?

Here is my code:

```
pose1 = PoseStamped()
pose1.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
pose1.header.frame_id = "head_plate_frame"
pose1.pose.position.x = 0.7
pose1.pose.position.y = -0.05
pose1.pose.position.z = 1.1
pose1.pose.orientation.x = 0.3
pose1.pose.orientation.y = 0.3
pose1.pose.orientation.z = 0.2
pose1.pose.orientation.w = 0.2

listener = tf.TransformListener()

try:
    position, quaternion = listener.lookupTransform("/base_link",  "/head_plate_frame", rospy.Time())

except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException,   tf.ExtrapolationException):
    print("Not working")
    pass
```

Comment: First, [check if the frames are connected](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf#Using_view_frames). Also, please [print the exception message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1483488/2084944)!

Answer (score 0):

You should first check that the transform is actually valid. Look at the TF tree with the following command to see that there is actually a path in the tree between the two links:

```
rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree
```

There is another utility that does the same thing that will output to a PDF file:

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

Once you're sure your tree looks as expected, you can move forward with my next recommendation. In general, I've found these TF lookups to never be very reliable. You will often hit that except block when your node first starts up because there may initially be a LookupException until enough TF messages are received, or there might be old data in the queues and you'll get an ExtrapolationException. These can happen even though everything in your TF tree is copacetic. A more robust way is to keep attempting the lookup until you get what you want:

```
position = None
quaternion = None
while position is None and quaternion is None:
    try:
        position, quaternion = listener.lookupTransform("/base_link",  "/head_plate_frame", rospy.Time())
    except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException,   tf.ExtrapolationException):
        print("Not working")
        pass
```

If you do this I might also recommend adding a timeout check so that it will only run through this while loop up to some time limit, that way you're not waiting for eternity. They have made this a little nicer to work with in [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2), there is a lookup call with a timeout built in, so you can do away with the while loop and it will just keep trying to lookup the transform until your timeout is hit. [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29) is a nice example of that.