# Try/except is not working, I use Pycharm and I use python 3.9 as the interpreter for my projects

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

When I use `try`/`except` and run it, it shows `Process finished with exit code 0`.

I use it on main.py and every function except for `try`/`except` functions properly.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()
try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
       print('listening..')
       voice = listener.listen(source)
       command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
       print(command)
except:
    pass
```

[Screen shot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjFPI.png)

Comment: Please: no screenshot please. Copy past the output: it helps us much more, and it is also easier for people who look for the same error (and solution)

Comment: When you ask a question on stackoverflow, please add the code, input/output results in formatted text instead of screenshot.

Comment: You are not printing anything in except block and silently 'pass' it. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483429/how-to-print-an-exception-in-python

Comment: try / except are not functions, but keywords or statements

Answer (score 1):

> When I use try/except and run it, it shows Process finished with exit code 0.

That is normal behaviour : Every program emits an exit code when it exits. By default, that is 0, which means "Ok, everything went fine." Exit code 1 means about as much as "Oops, the date you entered is not a date". Exit code 2 is reserved for fatal errrors, such as "Oh no, i accidentally deleted all your photos !". For special cases, such as -11 for a Segmentation Fault, there are more exit codes, but as long as you are writing small python programs, there is no need to know about them.
So, as you catch the error if there were one, the exit code of your program will be 0, unless there is an uncatched error somewhere else in the code, or you manually change the exit code by calling `sys.exit` (note : this will also cause your program to exit immediately).
At the moment, you are catching the error, so your program will continue working, but you are not notifying the user that an error occurred. You should catch the error and then print it out, as in following example:

```py
path = "/path/to/some/file"
try:
    f = open(path, "r") # try it with an existing and an inexisting file !
    print(f.read())
    f.close()
except FileNotFoundError as e: # handle non existing file
    print("Error: File", path, "not found")
except Exception as e: # handle all other errors
    print(e)
```

When you are handling all errors the same way, the second `except` block is enough.