# cataching exception don't know how to find out why it was caused so i can display reason

Tags: python

im using a stock trading api that throws a exception if a error happens. Write now when i put in the wrong order id i get the following exception

```
Exception has occurred: APIError
order_id is missing
```

I have added a try and catch so the exception will not go off
in the catch block I dont know how to find out how it happen so it simply displays a message saying "generic error"
how could i have it say order_id is missing?
code

```
def isClosed(id):
    global errorMesg
    try:
        y=api.get_order(id)
        if (y.status=="filled"):
           return 1
        return 0
    except:
# how can the below line disply why the exception went off?
        print("generic error") 
    return -1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print an exception in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1483429/2745495)

Comment: There could be other errors not just about order_id, so it's better to log or print the original exception, rather than printing out your own error message.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```